# Conditional mean and sum of previous N rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation, rolling-sum

Concerned is this exemplary pandas dataframe:

```
      Measurement  Trigger  Valid
   0          2.0    False   True
   1          4.0    False   True
   2          3.0    False   True
   3          0.0     True  False
   4        100.0    False   True
   5          3.0    False   True
   6          2.0    False   True
   7          1.0     True   True
```

Whenever `Trigger` is `True`, I wish to calculate sum and mean of the last 3 (starting from current) valid measurements. Measurements are considered valid, if the column `Valid` is `True`. So let's clarify using the two examples in the above dataframe:

1. `Index 3`: Indices `2,1,0` should be used. Expected `Sum = 9.0, Mean = 3.0`
2. `Index 7`: Indices `7,6,5` should be used. Expected `Sum = 6.0, Mean = 2.0`

I have tried `pandas.rolling` and creating new, shifted columns, but was not successful. See the following excerpt from my tests (which should directly run):

```
import unittest
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.util.testing import assert_series_equal

def create_sample_dataframe_2():
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {"Measurement" : [2.0,   4.0,   3.0,   0.0,   100.0, 3.0,   2.0,   1.0 ],
         "Valid"       : [True,  True,  True,  False, True,  True,  True,  True],
         "Trigger"     : [False, False, False, True,  False, False, False, True],
         })
    return df

def expected_result():
    return pd.DataFrame({"Sum" : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 9.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 6.0],
                         "Mean" :[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2.0]})

class Data_Preparation_Functions(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_backsummation(self):
        N_SUMMANDS = 3
        temp_vars = []

        df = create_sample_dataframe_2()
        for i in range(0,N_SUMMANDS):
            temp_var = "M_{0}".format(i)
            df[temp_var] = df["Measurement"].shift(i)
            temp_vars.append(temp_var)

        df["Sum"]  = df[temp_vars].sum(axis=1)
        df["Mean"] = df[temp_vars].mean(axis=1)
        df.loc[(df["Trigger"]==False), "Sum"] = np.nan
        df.loc[(df["Trigger"]==False), "Mean"] = np.nan

        assert_series_equal(expected_result()["Sum"],df["Sum"])
        assert_series_equal(expected_result()["Mean"],df["Mean"])

    def test_rolling(self):
        df = create_sample_dataframe_2()
        df["Sum"]  = df[(df["Valid"] == True)]["Measurement"].rolling(window=3).sum()
        df["Mean"] = df[(df["Valid"] == True)]["Measurement"].rolling(window=3).mean()

        df.loc[(df["Trigger"]==False), "Sum"] = np.nan
        df.loc[(df["Trigger"]==False), "Mean"] = np.nan
        assert_series_equal(expected_result()["Sum"],df["Sum"])
        assert_series_equal(expected_result()["Mean"],df["Mean"])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(Data_Preparation_Functions)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Any help or solution is greatly appreciated. Thanks and Cheers!

EDIT: Clarification: This is the resulting dataframe I expect:

```
      Measurement  Trigger  Valid   Sum   Mean
   0          2.0    False   True   NaN    NaN
   1          4.0    False   True   NaN    NaN
   2          3.0    False   True   NaN    NaN
   3          0.0     True  False   9.0    3.0
   4        100.0    False   True   NaN    NaN
   5          3.0    False   True   NaN    NaN
   6          2.0    False   True   NaN    NaN
   7          1.0     True   True   6.0    2.0
```

EDIT2: Another clarification:

I did indeed not miscalculate, but rather I did not make my intentions as clear as I could have. Here's another try using the same dataframe:

[image: Desired dataframe, relevant fields highlighted]

Let's first look at the `Trigger` column: We find the first `True` in index 3 (green rectangle). So index 3 is the point, where we start looking. There is no valid measurement at index 3 (Column `Valid` is `False`; red rectangle). So, we start to go further back in time, until we have accumulated three lines, where `Valid` is `True`. This happens for indices 2,1 and 0. For these three indices, we calculate the sum and mean of the column `Measurement` (blue rectangle):

- SUM: 2.0 + 4.0 + 3.0 = 9.0
- MEAN: (2.0 + 4.0 + 3.0) / 3 = 3.0

Now we start the next iteration of this little algorithm: Look again for the next `True` in the `Trigger` column. We find it at index 7 (green rectangle). There is also a valid measuremnt at index 7, so we include it this time. For our calculation, we use indices 7,6 and 5 (green rectangle), and thus get:

- SUM: 1.0 + 2.0 + 3.0 = 6.0
- MEAN: (1.0 + 2.0 + 3.0) / 3 = 2.0

I hope, this sheds more light on this little problem.

Comment: I have viewed a question like this , basically is to detect the cumsum,I now go to find it out!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Heres an option, take the 3 period rolling mean and sum

```
df['RollM'] = df.Measurement.rolling(window=3,min_periods=0).mean()

df['RollS'] = df.Measurement.rolling(window=3,min_periods=0).sum()
```

Now set False Triggers equals to `NaN`

```
df.loc[df.Trigger == False,['RollS','RollM']] = np.nan
```

yields

```
   Measurement  Trigger  Valid     RollM  RollS
0          2.0    False   True       NaN    NaN
1          4.0    False   True       NaN    NaN
2          3.0    False   True       NaN    NaN
3          0.0     True  False  2.333333    7.0
4        100.0    False   True       NaN    NaN
5          3.0    False   True       NaN    NaN
6          2.0    False   True       NaN    NaN
7          1.0     True   True  2.000000    6.0
```

---

Edit, updated to reflect valid argument

```
df['mean'],df['sum'] = np.nan,np.nan

roller = df.Measurement.rolling(window=3,min_periods=0).agg(['mean','sum'])

df.loc[(df.Trigger == True) & (df.Valid == True),['mean','sum']] = roller

df.loc[(df.Trigger == True) & (df.Valid == False),['mean','sum']] = roller.shift(1)
```

Yields

```
  Measurement  Trigger  Valid  mean  sum
0          2.0    False   True   NaN  NaN
1          4.0    False   True   NaN  NaN
2          3.0    False   True   NaN  NaN
3          0.0     True  False   3.0  9.0
4        100.0    False   True   NaN  NaN
5          3.0    False   True   NaN  NaN
6          2.0    False   True   NaN  NaN
7          1.0     True   True   2.0  6.0
```

Comment: This is not quite what I am looking for. To clarify, I added the expected result in tabular format to the original post.

Comment: Can you further explain how this is incorrect? It matches your sample, except for the numbers in index three, I believe you miss calculated them, and did the previous three, not including the current value @bolla